# Use decision variable only in constraint Gurobi Java

Tags: java, optimization, gurobi

Usually in Gurobi's Java interface I create the model by adding variables to the model with this for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        XobjectiveCoef = distance(i, j);
        X[i][j] = model.addVar(0.0, 1.0, XobjectiveCoef, GRB.BINARY, "x" + String.valueOf(i) + "_" + String.valueOf(j));

    }
}
```

When I am done I have my model which is the sum of all Xs over i and j, and I can use `X[i][j]` in any constraint I want with something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    GRBLinExpr expr = new GRBLinExpr();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        expr.addTerm(1.0, X[i][j]);
    }
    model.addConstr(expr, GRB.EQUAL, 1.0, "Name_of_constraint");
}
```

Now what I am  looking for, is a way to use decision variable only in a constraint and not in the model definition. I checked if `addVar` is available for `GRBLinExpr` but it is not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [GRBLinExpr](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/java_grblinexpr.html) and reuse it.  For example:

```
model.addConstr(expr, GRB.EQUAL, 1.0, "ct1");
expr.addTerm(1.0, Y);
expr.addTerm(1.0, Z).
model.addConstr(expr, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, 2.0, "ct2");
```

This may or may not be more efficient than creating a new [GRBVar](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/java_grbvar.html) object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get that I can reuse the expr, but I'm not sure I get the answer. Where and how do I create Y and Z if they are not in the model definition (thus not created with model.addVar(...))?.

Comment: Y and Z are new variables; the example simply shows that you can reuse the GRBLinExpr called expr.

Comment: Thank you for the example. But as you may see from the main question and the comment, the issue is not with reusing expressions, the issue is with creating a decision variable without adding it to the objective function. The constructor new GRBVar is unavailable, you have to go through model.addVar(...). But if I call model.addVar(...) it will add this variable to the objective function. Am I correct?

Comment: All variables are in the objective function. Some have a coefficient of zero.